# what is segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.
>
> [image: Example]

My code is:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,b;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int arr[3][b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int man[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    man[i]=0;
    int start,end,change;
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        start=arr[i][0]-1;
        end=arr[i][1]-1;
        change=arr[i][2];
        for(int j=start;j<=end;j++)
        {
            man[j]=man[j]+change;
            //printf("%d",change);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
    if(man[j]<man[j+1])
    {
        int temp=man[j+1];
        man[j+1]=man[j];
        man[j]=temp;
    }
    printf("%d",man[0]);
}
```

One of the input was

```
40 30
29 40 787
9 26 219
21 31 214
8 22 719
15 23 102
11 24 83
14 22 321
5 22 300
11 30 832
5 25 29
16 24 577
3 10 905
15 22 335
29 35 254
9 20 20
33 34 351
30 38 564
11 31 969
3 32 11
29 35 267
4 24 531
1 38 892
12 18 825
25 32 99
3 39 107
12 37 131
3 26 640
8 39 483
8 11 194
12 37 502
```

When the value of n and b is low my code gets executed but when the values are higher it shows **segmentation fault**.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the exact text of input used.

Comment: Use a debugger to find what line that causes the segfault. And also show relevant variable values at that point.

Comment: **There is a wikipedia page about [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)**. Did you read it? Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Read the documentation of your C compiler and of your debugger

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica posted

Comment: Take inspiration from existing open source code like  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - which should be useful to you. **StackOverflow is *not* a do my-home-work website**. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: SO is not an incremental debugging service.  Your edit invalidated an answer, confusing current and future users.  Rolling back..

Answer (score 1):

At least this problem: Wrong array dimensions.

```
// int arr[3][b];
int arr[b][3];

for(int i=0;i<b;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Baba_yaga Before `man[j]=man[j]+change;`, add `assert(j >= 0 && j < n);` to test array access there.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault - in your case at least - happens if you are trying to access memory that you did not allocate properly. E.g. your `arr` has a length of 3 integers in its first dimension. So if you enter b and it is bigger than 2, the nested loop will fail at the point you get to `scanf("%d", &arr[something bigger than or equal to 3][j])`. Probably you need to switch the loops around? Or the array dimensions?